# NetBeans GlassFish Server 4.0 failed for another server running on administrator port

Tags: java, netbeans, glassfish

Based on the title pretty much explain my problem.

I tried deployed my Web Service and the error pop up stating that `GlassFish Server 4.0: Authorization failed for another server running on administrator port`.

Anyone know how to deal with this problem? I checked with `Tools -> Server` and it just show the GlassFish Server 4.0 and no other servers running.

Comment: Have a look with whatever tool to inspect running processes your operating system provides, sometimes (rarely) Netbeans loses track of a running fish.  If that's the case the quickest and easiest way is to kill that instance and start a new one in Netbeans.

Comment: @fvu Well, doesn't seem to have fish slipped away.

Comment: admin port is 4848, could you check with netstat -l -n -p whether there's a program listening on that port and if so what program?

Comment: @fvu, oh well, restart my computer and problem is fixed. Stupid me for asking such question. Sorry for wasting your time.

Comment: No worries, if rebooting is possible it can be the quickest and easiest fix.

Answer (score 10):

To fix this I opened `Services > Servers > GlassFish Server 4.0 > Properties`. Then removed user and password (totally blank) and suddenly it worked.

Comment: However, a restart is required [important].

Answer (score 2):

Deleting the servers' username and password is the easiest way to fix it...

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem... I think the problem was in password. I don`t know why or how it happened but  my glassfish password changed yesterday and it happened also today, so if someone is going through this problem, try to check your password in folder c:...\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\7.4\config\GF_4.0\domain1\config\local-password

Comment: In GlassFish 4.1. I think this file can be located in C:\Users\your_user\AppData\Roaming\NetBeans\8.0\config\GlassFishEE6\Properties.

Answer (score 1):

**This case maybe cause by:**
- An other previous application
- Other Glassfish instance is running.

**You can do these solutions:**
- After installing, we call Glassfish directory called `%GLASSFISH_HOME%`. Look for

```
`%GLASSFISH%`\glassfish\bin\stopserv.bat
```

then run this file (in Windows), if you use Linux or MacOS, try something similar. (For example: in my computer: `C:\tools\glassfish4\glassfish\bin\startserv.bat`).
- Restart computer (the same as comments below the question).

Answer (score 0):

I know it's an old post and this may be a little late;

But I got it running by removing the server from the IDE and then adding it again with the credentials initialized from the beginning (in the configuration dialog you have to go through to add the server)

Hope it Helps anybody.